# Is there any external tool in php/java to generateChangelog files for all database object?

Tags: xml, bash, xslt, liquibase, xmllint

I am trying to add the `liquibase` tool into my development environment to manage database migrations. Given the feature set it looks very flexible and promising. My first obvious question is how I can export all the existing schema into individual files (tables, triggers, functions and stored procedures ). ?

Is there any tool/extension for liquibase to perform such task.

I have tried command line option `liquibase generateChangelogs` , but unfortunately it generates single changelog file ( without stored objects -fun/pro/trig)

anything using bash/java/any linux standard xml processing command line tool is appreciable

**Here is what I want to do :**
 -Have xml templates for mysql function/stored procedure /trigger/table etc

- query existing database for all
  tables/function triggers etc..    go through each and parse
  respective template and generate changelog file for each object
- -- store each file in respective director under current location e.g

  /database

  ```
   ---/functions

   ---/procedures

   ---/triggers

   ---/views

   ---/tables
  ```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, but you can generate the initial changelog with the command and then write a script that separates the objects. Afterwards just create a master changelog that includes the others.

Check my post on Liquibase ( http://scalabilitycookbook.com/2012/10/05/control-your-database-schema/ ) for details.

Comment: thanks @Mirko Adari , I tried sth with with xslt[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379447/xslt-change-override-attribute-on-copy-of-not-applied-using-saxon/14379957#14379957].This splits out the changelots out to individual files  but I am unable to fetch the triggers/procedure and functions. I am looking forward to do sth with xslt and ODBC connectivity. Cheers