# XSLT change/override attribute on copy-of not applied (using saxon )

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I have a xslt like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:db="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">    
      <xsl:for-each select="db:databaseChangeLog/db:changeSet"> 
          <xsl:if test="name(*[1])='createTable'">  
          <xsl:result-document  href="base/tables/{position()}_{name(*[1])}_{*[1]/@tableName}.xml">
           <databaseChangeLog 
                xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">

                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>                       

                <xsl:copy-of select="../db:changeSet[name(*[1])='createIndex' and *[1]/@tableName= current()/*[1]/@tableName ]" />

            </databaseChangeLog> 
        </xsl:result-document>      
        </xsl:if> 
      </xsl:for-each>     
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="copy">
       <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="db:changeSet/@author" mode="copy">
        <xsl:attribute name="author">
            <xsl:value-of select="'sakhunzai'"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## XML partial file

```
<changeSet author="xxx (generated)" id="1358259674512-26">
        <createIndex indexName="category_id" tableName="teams" unique="false">
            <column name="audience_id"/>
        </createIndex>
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="xxx (generated)" id="1358259674512-29">
    <createIndex indexName="id" tableName="users" unique="false">
        <column name="id"/>
        <column name="career_lead_id"/>
    </createIndex>
</changeSet>
```

I want to override the attribute values of changeSet (author and id). Please help me fix the xslt.

Everything is working fine but @author  atrribute value  is not change in target xml files 
note: since xsltproc failed to do ,I switched to saxon java based processor e.g

`java -jar /usr/local/liquibase/saxon/saxon9he.jar  common.xml table.xslt`

## **Working XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:db="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">    
      <xsl:for-each select="db:databaseChangeLog/db:changeSet[db:createTable]"> 
          <xsl:result-document  href="base/tables/{position()}_{name(*[1])}_{*[1]/@tableName}.xml">
           <databaseChangeLog 
                xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">

                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="copy"/>                       

                <xsl:apply-templates select="../db:changeSet[db:createIndex and *[1]/@tableName= current()/*[1]/@tableName ]"  mode="copy"/>

            </databaseChangeLog> 
        </xsl:result-document>
      </xsl:for-each>     
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()" mode="copy">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:attribute name="author">sakhunzai</xsl:attribute>
           <xsl:copy-of select="@id|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<xsl:copy-of />` does not cause templates to be applied.  It just creates an exact copy.  How about changing this line

```
<xsl:template match="db:changeSet/@author">
```

to this:

```
<xsl:template match="db:changeSet/@author" mode="copy">
```

Adding this template:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="copy">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and finally changing this:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="../db:changeSet[name(*[1])='createIndex' and *[1]/@tableName= current()/*[1]/@tableName ]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>                       
</xsl:copy-of>
```

To this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select=="../db:changeSet[name(*[1])='createIndex' and *[1]/@tableName = current()/*[1]/@tableName]" 
   mode="copy" />
```

As a side note, this looks a bit redundant:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="current()[name()='changeSet']">                        
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:copy-of>
```

The current node necessarily has the name "changeSet", by virtue of the for-each loop.  I believe this should suffice for that part:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="." />
```

Full XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:db="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">    
      <xsl:for-each select="db:databaseChangeLog/db:changeSet"> 
          <xsl:if test="name(*[1])='createTable'">  
          <xsl:document href="base/tables/{position()}_{name(*[1])}_{*[1]/@tableName}.xml">
           <databaseChangeLog 
                xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">

                    <xsl:copy-of select="." />                        

                    <xsl:apply-templates select="../db:changeSet[name(*[1])='createIndex' and *[1]/@tableName= current()/*[1]/@tableName ]" mode="copy" />
            </databaseChangeLog> 
        </xsl:document>     
        </xsl:if> 
      </xsl:for-each>     
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="copy">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="db:changeSet/@author" mode="copy">
     <xsl:attribute name="author">
        <xsl:value-of select="'sakhunzai'"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I do think the XSLT could be further improved like the following.  Give it a try if you like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:db="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="db:changeSet" />

  <xsl:template match="db:changeSet[db:createTable]">
    <xsl:document href="base/tables/{position()}_{name(*[1])}_{*[1]/@tableName}.xml">
      <databaseChangeLog
           xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">

        <xsl:copy-of select="." />

        <xsl:apply-templates select="../db:changeSet[db:createIndex and *[1]/@tableName = current()/*[1]/@tableName ]" mode="copy" />
      </databaseChangeLog>
    </xsl:document>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="copy">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="db:changeSet/@author" mode="copy">
    <xsl:attribute name="author">
      <xsl:value-of select="'sakhunzai'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: would you please add the complete xslt with modification at the end of your answer. I am just confused where to put modifications

Comment: I fixed the xslt as you suggested but @mode is not working with saxon (sorry I switched to saxon ) please check my edits

Comment: Error at xsl:copy-of on line 15 column 131 of table.xslt:
  XTSE0090: Attribute `@mode` is not allowed on element <xsl:copy-of>
Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected., therefore I have to remove `@mode`

Comment: Line 15 should be an `<xsl:apply-templates>`, not `<xsl:copy-of>`.

Comment: `<changeSet>xxx (generated)1358259674512-29    </changeSet>` for createIndex part . While createTable port is copied as its with attribute not modified. thanks

Comment: thanks for your suggestions , plz check my working example . your suggestions were very helpful

Answer (score 1):

The xsl:copy-of element does not allow child elements. It looks like xsltproc is not validating your stylesheet carefully enough.

Comment: yes you are right I am using saxon now , plz check my updates xslt and xml file

Comment: Sorry, I hate working with edited questions. It leaves it very unclear whether you still have a problem, and if so, what it is. If you still have a problem please start a new topic.